# List and edit all class declaration usages

Tags: python

So I have a big project with a `UniqueException` class that simply inherits from Exception class.

Now, all over the project I have A LOT of `UniqueException` instances (some of them conditioned).

At some point in order to use some automation tools in my project, whenever there's an exception in my project I want to identify the Error, so I added a new attribute to `UniqueException` that calls `self.id`

So for example whenever I want to do an exception I'd do so like that: `raise UniqueException(id=41234, exception=error)`

So there are two problems I currently facing using this new self.id attribute:

1. There are a lot of `UniqueException` instances all over the project without an `id` attribute that I want to set, I want them to be random but not to be changed. E.g. if in `file1.py` in line 60 there's a `raise UniqueException(exception='Some error occurred in this place')` instance, I want to to be replaced with for example `raise UniqueException(exception='Some error occurred in this place', id=412341234)`
2. Whenever I write a code I don't want to think about a random ID to put.

So the solution I came up with is to write a script that go through my project and check if the id attribute exists, if not it would edit my code and put one.

So the first problem is to locate all instances of UniqueException and check if they have id attribute, I tried to google a bit and found out about `gc` library, I tried to do something like that:

```py
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, UniqueException):
        print(obj)
```

But it only prints instantiated unique exception and not all usages.

And the 2nd problem and once I located an instance of UniqueException, how do I edit the file itself? it feels like i need to interpret the whole python script like PyCharm do for example.

Comment: In point 1, the original and replacement are identical. It's not clear, though, how you are distinguishing between exceptions that should have an id and exceptions that can assign themselves a random id (something that I presume `UniqueException.__init__` handles).

Comment: @chepner sorry it was a typo, I fixed point 1. And the same way that PyCharm IDE for example can process my code usages and list them and also tell if some attributes exists, I want this ability also via Python script - I'd like to list all python usages and maybe also to edit them via python

Comment: you can always personalize the creation of your personalize exception however you want, same as any other class

Comment: @Copperfield The problem is that there are thousands of UniqueException instances, how can I make a *consistent* random id for each one of them? by consistent I mean tomorrow I'll have an exception I would have the same id as I had the day before if it failed in the same place.

Comment: make a default value for your id argument, in your UniqueException constructor

Comment: @Copperfield to what value? let's say random value? it would have different random value in each run, i want fixed value for each instance.

Comment: pick a convenient value? I don't really get the random part you mention

Comment: @Copperfield I want random id for each exception instance but i want it to be consistent which means I can't use like a random() function. A convention name means that all instances would have the same name, no?

Comment: so, let me if I understood it correctly, let said you have 2 functions fun1 and fun2, both can throw your UniqueException and do so like `raise UniqueException (exception="some msj")`, without changing that you want it so, for example, the exception from fun1 get the id=1 and the one from fun2 get the id=2, is that correct?

Comment: Yep! exactly @Copperfield

Comment: I will look into it and see if I can find something, I have one idea but I don't know if that work or not

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish a self identifying exception we need dive in in how the exceptions work and the data model around them, luckily for us that is not too complicate:

When we do raise of our exception, one instance of it is created, and then the special traceback object (if any) is attached to it and then the rest of the exception machinery do its thing, but we don't care for that last part, what we want is the traceback, that is how we will determine the point of origin of our personalize exception.

The [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects) for an given raised exception is located in the `__traceback__`  special attribute, this object possessed several special attribute of it own, two of which are of interest to us `tb_next` and `tb_frame`; the traceback is like a linked list that record the journey for each execution frame (aka the currently executing function/class method/etc) from the surfice until the actual point of origin of the raised exception, and `tb_next` contains that next step, we follow that until there is no more step forward and once there we take a look at the frame object contain in `tb_frame`.

The [frame](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects) object
represent a execution frame and if we get here as previously described then this is where our exception was actually raised, this also have a bunch of attributes, of those the one of interest is `f_code` which is an code object that is, well, the piece of code being executed that raised our exception.

And we finally got to the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-55) object, here we will determine the function that raise the exception, as the others it have a bunch of attributes, of those the one of interest is `co_name` which is the name of the function, and `co_filename` which is the file from where this code object was compiled, and maybe `co_firstlineno` which is the first line number of the function, that should be enough to make some sort of identifying scheme of your liking.

Now for an sample code.

(EDIT: added new scheme)

For this sample the identifying scheme is just a dictionary of the file line, name and file of the function to a selected id done with the help of the inspect module

```
from pprint import pprint
import inspect, pathlib

ID_SCHEME = {}

def id_scheme(code):
    """take a code object and return its assigned id"""
    function_name = code.co_name
    file_path     = code.co_filename
    line          = code.co_firstlineno
    key           = line, function_name, file_path
    return ID_SCHEME.get( key, f"function not in the escheme {key}" )

def make_scheme():
    """generator of the scheme key"""
    def extract_data(code):
        """take a code object and return its information of interest"""
        return code.co_firstlineno, code.co_name, code.co_filename  
    gdata = dict(globals())
    print("making scheme")
    base = pathlib.Path(__file__)
    for k,v in gdata.items():
        if inspect.isfunction(v):
            data=extract_data(v.__code__)
            if base <= pathlib.Path(data[-1]): #with this we make sure is something from this folder or a subfolder there off
                print(f"{k=}")
                yield data
        elif inspect.isclass(v) and not issubclass(v,Exception) and not k.startswith("_"):
            for nm,m in inspect.getmembers(v):
                if inspect.isfunction(m):
                    data = extract_data(m.__code__)
                    if base <= pathlib.Path(data[-1]):
                        print(f"{k=} {nm=}")
                        yield data
    print("scheme done")

class UniqueException(Exception):
    
    def __init__(self, exception, id=None):
        super().__init__(exception)
        self._id = id

    @property
    def id(self):
        if self._id is None:
            if (tb := self.__traceback__):
                while tb.tb_next is not None:
                    tb = tb.tb_next
                frame = tb.tb_frame
                self._id = id_scheme(frame.f_code)
            else:
                self._id = "undeterminable"
        return self._id
        

def fun1():
    print("fun1")
    raise UniqueException("exception from fun1")

def fun2():
    print("fun2")
    raise UniqueException("exception from fun2")

def fun3():
    fun1()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        fun2()

class B():

    def boom(self):
        raise UniqueException("exception from B().boom()")


        
            
ID_SCHEME.update((k,v) for v,k in enumerate(make_scheme()))
pprint(ID_SCHEME)

print("\n"*2)

try:
    fun1()
except UniqueException as e:
    print("got exception from fun1: ",repr(e))
    print("with id=",e.id)
    
try:
    fun2()
except UniqueException as e:
    print("got exception from fun2: ",repr(e))
    print("with id=",e.id)
    

try:
    fun3()
except UniqueException as e:
    print("got exception from fun3: ",repr(e))
    print("with id=",e.id)

try:
    A()
except UniqueException as e:
    print("got exception from A(): ",repr(e))
    print("with id=",e.id)


try:
    b=B()
    b.boom()
except UniqueException as e:
    print("got exception from B().boom(): ",repr(e))
    print("with id=",e.id)
```

and the output

```
making scheme
k='id_scheme'
k='make_scheme'
k='fun1'
k='fun2'
k='fun3'
k='A' nm='__init__'
k='B' nm='boom'
scheme done
{(15, 'id_scheme', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 0,
 (23, 'make_scheme', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 1,
 (65, 'fun1', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 2,
 (69, 'fun2', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 3,
 (73, 'fun3', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 4,
 (77, '__init__', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 5,
 (82, 'boom', 'C:\\Users\\copperfield\\Documents\\StackOverflow\\72662965.py'): 6}



fun1
got exception from fun1:  UniqueException('exception from fun1')
with id= 2
fun2
got exception from fun2:  UniqueException('exception from fun2')
with id= 3
fun1
got exception from fun3:  UniqueException('exception from fun1')
with id= 2
fun2
got exception from A():  UniqueException('exception from fun2')
with id= 3
got exception from B().boom():  UniqueException('exception from B().boom()')
with id= 6
```

---

if you want to make a dict like ID_SCHEME from the example in a more automatic fashion you can use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to gather all the names more easily, along with the `__all__` attribute, and if you didn't defined one for your module, you can [automatize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561931/5644961) that too

---

to help you make your id_scheme, you can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module, to find all the thing of interest you want to add to your scheme

```
>>> import inspect
>>> for k,v in list(globals().items()):
...     if inspect.isfunction(v):
...         print(k)
... 
...         
id_scheme
fun1
fun2
fun3
>>>
```

once you find those you can get their [code](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-33) in the special   attribute `__code__`, with some combination of the previously mention you can build and id_sheme of your liking

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort!
I was thinking about a traceback as a unique ID, but the problem is whenever I'll make a changes in my code, e.g. deepen the traceback or change function names, it will change the trackback. How do I solve that problem using a traceback as unique identifier?

Comment: no matter how deep you go, this should get to the original function as show in the example with fun3, now if you change the name of the function, well at least the co_filename should be the same and/or adjust by the co_firstlineno somehow, if you don't change the actual code of the function then the co_code I think should remain the same, you can apply some form of check sum/hash algorithm to get an unique number out of it... is otherwise impossible to guard against every possibility unless you manually go and put some id there, otherwise the id_scheme is up to you

Comment: you can get the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-33) of all your functions in the special attribute `__code__` you can then list all your function and automatically generate some sort of mapping and create that way your id_scheme that way you don't need to hardcode like in the example

Comment: there is also the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module, that you can use build some sort automatic id_scheme

Comment: I added a sample of an automatic id scheme maker

Comment: As you mentioned by yourself, the code can be changed as well, and also the function name and the stack trace. So moving forward to another solution I found the library "AST" which can tell me if I haven't put an self.id in an Exception instantiate, but I couldn't find yet a way to over-ride the file. I saw AST.unparse() function, if you would know how to use it to overrride the IDs in my files directory it would be awesome!

Comment: well, in that case if that library can tell you the instances where you don't put the id, then go with @AvitanD suggestion, you already know where to look, right?, simple replace "UniqueException(", with "UniqueException(id=blah," in that place where blah if your desire id, or just blindly replace all "UniqueException(" with "UniqueException(_autoid=blah," and in the exception `__init__` check if received an id and if it didn't use the autoid...

Comment: Yeah that's good idea! :-) if you'd make another answer with this idea using the AST i'll accept your answer.

Comment: well, that is more like AvitanD idea with your idea of the ast, accept his/her instead... or post your final solution if you want to share it here...

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound very best-practice-y.
If you have a need for identifying exceptions you should create new exceptions for every one of your use cases.

To answer your question nonetheless, i would go with building a script that reads your files, finds `UniqueException()` using regex and replaces it with the right call (which includes a random if).

Comment: The question is if there are pythonic ways to do so and not just a regex which makes the problem a bit more harder (need to take into consideration multi-line, comments and so on..)